# This is the error i encountered while updating my gradle for firebase realtime Data base - "Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-database:"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a Feedback Button for my android app for which I was trying to use the real time Database of firebase but when I update the Gradle with

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'  I am getting the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to project level build.gradle & check if it has following code snippet:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
     }
   }
 }
```

Now check below dependency lines

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1'
```

Comment: Thank you that was a silly mistake. I didn't add the version number.

Comment: No worries, we all do silly mistakes many times. Kindly upvote answer if it worked for you. It will help others too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add Firebase libraries without a version number, as you see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-sdks), It looks like you didn't add the line of code that specifies that you want to use the [Firebase BoM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more#bom).  Your dependencies should look like this:

```
dependencies {
  // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')

  // Declare the dependencies for the desired Firebase products without specifying versions
  // For example, declare the dependencies for Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
}
```